# Matching first block of text from a file, between 2 strings

Tags: bash, scripting, centos7, sed, awk

I'm trying to match **only the first** block of text between 2 strings: 'menuentry ' and '}' from a file as follows:

**Input file:**

```
(some irrelevant text)
menuentry 'My Customized Linux, with Linux 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64' --class centos --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64-advanced-/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_root' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod xfs
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  2e420275-8578-449d-9217-ce6d9ae35f70
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2e420275-8578-449d-9217-ce6d9ae35f70
        fi
        linux16 /vmlinuz-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_root ro  nomodeset rd.lvm.lv=sysvg/lv_swap vconsole.keymap=us rd.lvm.lv=sysvg/lv_root vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rootfstype=xfs crashkernel=auto quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
        initrd16 /initramfs-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64.img
}
menuentry 'My Customized Linux (Rescue)' --class centos --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-0-rescue-2e4c8e37e48347b0b4fa7095fbd707db-advanced-/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_root' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod xfs
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  2e420275-8578-449d-9217-ce6d9ae35f70
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2e420275-8578-449d-9217-ce6d9ae35f70
        fi
        linux16 /vmlinuz-0-rescue-2e4c8e37e48347b0b4fa7095fbd707db root=/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_root ro  nomodeset rd.lvm.lv=sysvg/lv_swap vconsole.keymap=us rd.lvm.lv=sysvg/lv_root vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rootfstype=xfs crashkernel=auto quiet
        initrd16 /initramfs-0-rescue-2e4c8e37e48347b0b4fa7095fbd707db.img
}
(some more irrelevant text)
```

**output should be:**

```
menuentry 'My Customized Linux, with Linux 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64' --class centos --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64-advanced-/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_root' {
            load_video
            set gfxpayload=keep
            insmod gzio
            insmod part_msdos
            insmod xfs
            set root='hd0,msdos1'
            if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  2e420275-8578-449d-9217-ce6d9ae35f70
            else
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2e420275-8578-449d-9217-ce6d9ae35f70
            fi
            linux16 /vmlinuz-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_root ro  nomodeset rd.lvm.lv=sysvg/lv_swap vconsole.keymap=us rd.lvm.lv=sysvg/lv_root vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rootfstype=xfs crashkernel=auto quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
            initrd16 /initramfs-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64.img

}
```

I'm using sed for this as follows:

**sed -n '/^menuentry /,/^}$/p;' /boot/grub2/grub.cfg**

But always get the whole text between the first 'menuentry' and last '}'

```
    [root@ball ~]# sed -n '/^menuentry /,/^}$/p;' /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
menuentry 'My Customized Linux, with Linux 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64' --class centos --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64-advanced-/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_root' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod xfs
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  2e420275-8578-449d-9217-ce6d9ae35f70
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2e420275-8578-449d-9217-ce6d9ae35f70
        fi
        linux16 /vmlinuz-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_root ro  nomodeset rd.lvm.lv=sysvg/lv_swap vconsole.keymap=us rd.lvm.lv=sysvg/lv_root vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rootfstype=xfs crashkernel=auto quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
        initrd16 /initramfs-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64.img
}
menuentry 'My Customized Linux (Rescue)' --class centos --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-0-rescue-2e4c8e37e48347b0b4fa7095fbd707db-advanced-/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_root' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod xfs
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  2e420275-8578-449d-9217-ce6d9ae35f70
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2e420275-8578-449d-9217-ce6d9ae35f70
        fi
        linux16 /vmlinuz-0-rescue-2e4c8e37e48347b0b4fa7095fbd707db root=/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_root ro  nomodeset rd.lvm.lv=sysvg/lv_swap vconsole.keymap=us rd.lvm.lv=sysvg/lv_root vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rootfstype=xfs crashkernel=auto quiet
        initrd16 /initramfs-0-rescue-2e4c8e37e48347b0b4fa7095fbd707db.img
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one line sed

```
sed -n '/^menuentry/,/\}$/{p;/^\}$/q}'
```

`/^\}$/q` means that "if the line matches with pattern `/^\}$/` then quit"

Comment: Works like a charm. A great one liner

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using multiple passes

```
sed -n '/^menuentry /,$p' /boot/grub2/grub.cfg | tr '\n' '~' | sed 's/~menuentry.*//' | tr '~' '\n'
```

#### Explanation

- `sed -n '/^menuentry /,$p' /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` - remove the head of the file up to the first `menuentry`
- `tr '\n' '~'` - convert the output into a single line
- `sed 's/~menuentry.*//'` - use sed to remove from  `\nmenuentry` (which is now `~menuentry`) to the end of the string
- `tr '~' '\n'` - restore the string back to mulitiline output

Answer (score 1):

If Perl will do...

```
    perl -lne '$p=1 if(/^menuentry/);print if $p;exit if (/^}$/)' /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

gives

```
menuentry 'My Customized Linux, with Linux 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64' --class centos --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64-advanced-/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_root' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod xfs
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  2e420275-8578-449d-9217-ce6d9ae35f70
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2e420275-8578-449d-9217-ce6d9ae35f70
        fi
        linux16 /vmlinuz-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/sysvg-lv_root ro  nomodeset rd.lvm.lv=sysvg/lv_swap vconsole.keymap=us rd.lvm.lv=sysvg/lv_root vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rootfstype=xfs crashkernel=auto quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
        initrd16 /initramfs-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64.img
}
```

or this:

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN{$/="\nmenuentry "};if($.==2){print $/,$_;last}' /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

(This version sets the perl line splitting to end with the start of the menuentry line, then prints the "second" stanza which is actually the one you want.